# Adding column to numpy array based on if/then of data in array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array like so:

```
np.array([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")])
```

I need to create fourth "column" to the array based on an if then of the 2nd column for example.

If `[:,2] == 1` then newcolumn = 'Wow' else 'Dud'

So that it returns something like:

```
[("a",1,"x","Wow"),("b",2,"y","Dud"),("c",1,"z","Wow")]
```

As I'm going to be processing around 100 million rows of data speed is of the essence here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you mean your input is `np.array([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")])`?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Show us what you are doing with the `pandas` dataframe.  Working with an array isn't inherently faster.  By the way did you even look at the array created by the first expression?  Is that what us to work with?

Comment: If an answer helped you, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pandas

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.DataFrame([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

> ```
> df
>   col1  col2 col3
> 0    a     1    x
> 1    b     2    y
> 2    c     1    z
> ```

create a function to operate on rows (doesn't have to be a lambda), and use apply on `axis=1` (rows). This will give you the new column.

```
>> b = lambda row: "Wow" if row['col2'] == 1 else "Dud" 
>> new_col = df.apply(b, axis=1)
```

> ```
> new_col
> 0    Wow
> 1    Dud
> 2    Wow
> dtype: object
> ```

add your new column to the dataframe.

```
>> df['new_col'] = new_col
```

> ```
> df
>   col1  col2 col3 new_col
> 0    a     1    x     Wow
> 1    b     2    y     Dud
> 2    c     1    z     Wow
> ```

and convert back to list of tuples

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df[['col1','col2','col3','new_col']].to_numpy()]
```

> ```
> [('a', 1, 'x', 'Wow'), ('b', 2, 'y', 'Dud'), ('c', 1, 'z', 'Wow')]
> ```

Suggestion: Don't use lists of tuples. Do use dataframes. Let alone for large data.

Comment: I do NOT want to use Pandas. I want to keep it in Numpy. I've done it in Pandas, it was too slow(6-8 hours to process 90M rows). I want to avoid Pandas if possible, and as Numpy is inherently faster than Pandas- especially when dealing with such large sets of data. I'm just not as good with Numpy as I am with Pandas.

Comment: `numpy` is faster only if you use the whole-array methods.  Iterating (list comprehension) on an array will be just as slow as a `pandas.apply`.  If you can do the job with a whole `numpy` array, you can do with a whole Series.  And it's easier to create a new dataframe column than make a new array.

Comment: @user3220955 Also added a only-numpy method. Please have a look

Comment: I was able to use the numpy method and did a test that iterated through the list and processed it around 10x faster than the dataframe. Thank you for your help Gulzar.

Answer (score 1):

Notice dtype has to accomodate for the longest strings it will ever hold, in this case, of length 3

```
  a = np.array([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")], dtype='<U3')
```

> ```
> a
> array([['a', '1', 'x'],
>        ['b', '2', 'y'],
>        ['c', '1', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
> ```

Create a placeholder array up front, for speed. Notice Type is string, but you could leave it empty, I am not sure how it will affect speed. It would be better to only use the same type in your array and not have numpy hold non-numeric types.

```
> b = np.new_arr = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] + 1), dtype=a.dtype)
```

Assign `a` to first columns

```
> b[:, :a.shape[1]] = a
```

poll relevant column for relevant condition

```
> cond_indices = a[:, 1] == '1'
```

assign by mask

```
>b[cond_indices, a.shape[1]] = "Wow"
>b[~cond_indices, a.shape[1]] = "Dud"
```

enjoy

> ```
> b
> array([['a', '1', 'x', 'Wow'],
>        ['b', '2', 'y', 'Dud'],
>        ['c', '1', 'z', 'Wow']], dtype='<U3')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your array constructor produces a string dtype:

```
In [73]: arr = np.array([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")])                                   
In [74]: arr                                                                                     
Out[74]: 
array([['a', '1', 'x'],
       ['b', '2', 'y'],
       ['c', '1', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

2nd column?

```
In [75]: arr[:,2]                                                                                
Out[75]: array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U1')
In [76]: arr[:,1]                                                                                
Out[76]: array(['1', '2', '1'], dtype='<U1')
```

go to test against string:

```
In [77]: arr[:,1]=="1"                                                                           
Out[77]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

Make a new array with the desired strings:

```
In [78]: np.where(arr[:,1]=="1", "Wow","Dud")                                                    
Out[78]: array(['Wow', 'Dud', 'Wow'], dtype='<U3')
```

join it with the orginal to make a new array (this is not in-place):

```
In [79]: np.column_stack((arr, Out[78]))                                                         
Out[79]: 
array([['a', '1', 'x', 'Wow'],
       ['b', '2', 'y', 'Dud'],
       ['c', '1', 'z', 'Wow']], dtype='<U3')
```

but with pandas

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame([("a",1,"x"),("b",2,"y"),("c",1,"z")], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'
    ...: ])                                                                                      
In [81]: df                                                                                      
Out[81]: 
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     1    x
1    b     2    y
2    c     1    z
In [82]: df["newcol"] = np.where(df["col2"]==1, "Wow","Dud")                                     
In [83]: df                                                                                      
Out[83]: 
  col1  col2 col3 newcol
0    a     1    x    Wow
1    b     2    y    Dud
2    c     1    z    Wow
```

`pandas` stores its data in arrays, either one per dataframe or one per series (column).  Switching to `numpy` does not automatically make things faster.  Row iteration on an array is just as slow as a row `apply` on a dataframe.  But as I show here, a whole-array operation often can be applied to the whole data frame.  And adding a column to a dataframe is easier than adding an column to an array.